# Forwarding Old URL with trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hyperlink, seo, http-status-code-301

I was using the Divi builder with WordPress for quite some time to build my site. I outgrew it and switched to Webflow so that custom code would be easier to achieve. I have gotten the site live, but there is a major problem...

Divi Builder created URL's that looked like this

https://hike2hike.com/eldorado-peak-climb-washington/

Now that I have all the site files on my hosts server, the URL's I am getting look like this

https://hike2hike.com/eldorado-peak-climb-washington.html <-- **Trailing slash is missing and .HTML added**

and are missing the trailing slash.

I have edited the .htaccess file with the following code:

```
# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://www.hike2hike.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on the directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.hike2hike.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hike2hike.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But, I am still getting a server error when I try to use the old links to get into the site.

Any thoughts on how I get the old URLs to transfer to the new site URL's so I don't lose all the SEO I have built up over 5 years?

Answer (score 2):

Good try, IMHO I believe you almost had it right, you need to place your https forcing rule to the top of your htaccess else it will be complete redirect of URLs; corrected your regex in your last rule of checking if uri is ending with `/` or not too, could you please try following once. Fair warning I couldn't test it as of now.

After placing this .htaccess file, please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
# Force HTTPS and WWW 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hike2hike.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hike2hike.com/%1 [R=301,L]


# Include trailing slash on the directory 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://www.hike2hike.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226659/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-forwarding-old-url-with-trailing-slash).